# how to calculate resistors' value?

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin, electrical

I'm new to electronic circuit, I'm solving some problems in the book and come across this one, but I cannot calculate the value of Rs and Rp according to the info provided. Can someone help me with this, I solved equations using Thevenin but there is no solution for the value of those two resistors
(sorry for my bad English, I'm Vietnamese )
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two unknowns: \$R_s\$ and \$R_p\$. I.e. you need two equations.

- **1st equation:**
  \$V_g\$ with \$R_g\$ and \$R_s\$ form a Thevenin source with \$V_{Th1} = V_g\$ and \$R_{Th1} = R_g + R_s\$

  Transform this Thevenin source into a Norton source: \$R_{N1} = R_{Th1} = R_g + R_s\$.

  Include \$R_p\$ to form a new Norton source whose \$R_{N2} = R_{N1} || R_p\$.

  Transform it back to a Thevenin source \$R_{Th2} = R_{N2} = R_{N1} || R_p\$.

  The resistance of the final Thevenins source is supposed to equal that of   the starting Thevenin source, i.e.

  \$R_{Th1} = R_{Th2}\$  i.e.
  \$R_g = R_{N1} || R_p = (R_g + R_s) || R_p\$
- **2nd equation:**
  You get from \$V_g / V_o = 0.125\$
  It depends how \$V_o\$ is defined (I think the problem is not clear about this): either with \$R_L\$ attached or without \$R_L\$ connected. I'm not sure which one is the case (the diagramm actually says with \$R_L\$; but \$R_L\$'s value is not given).
  In either case use the voltage divider formula.

Comment: but the problem says Req = 100, and this Req is the resistor of  Attenuator. Does it mean that when this Attenuator is not attached to the circuit yet, then Req = Rs + Rp = 100 ?

Comment: @Curd I think the situation is absolutely clear. In the schematic diagram, the load ***\$R_L\$*** is clearly attached to the output of the attenuator. So, both the ***\$R_s\$*** and ***\$R_p\$*** will be functions of ***\$R_L\$***.

Comment: @Uvuvwevwevwe Onyetenyevwe Ugwe No, ***\$R_{eq}\$*** equals ***\$R_p||(R_s+R_g)\$*** and the second condition says \$R_g = R_{eq}\$.

Comment: That's exactly right, but the diagram definitely makes it look like some (possibly series) combination of just Rp and Rs which is equal to 100.

Comment: Thank god for user name autocompletion

Comment: @Tim Mottram I don't agree. The red arrow clearly indicates what resistance has to be seen from that direction. The ideal voltage source has zero internal resistance, so the resulting resistance is as I stated.

Comment: @Uvuvwevwevwe Onyetenyevwe Ugwe Have you noticed my solution? Unlike the first one, it's fully general and complete, don't you think?

Comment: @Eric Best There is an arrow apparently pointing to a dashed box labeled "attenuator" containing Rs and Rp, it's meaning is unclear. Of course it can't actually mean the series combination of Rs and Rp is equal to 100 - because it wouldn't work if it did. All I was saying is that the arrow is confusing - which it clearly is because people were confused.

Comment: @Tim Mottram In my opinion (and as far as I know) it is something like a "common convention" in the circuit theory to indicate this way (by an arrow pointing to an input or output of a circuit) the input or output impedance (the overall impedance that "can be seen" in the indicated direction). (I can say that during my over 50 years long work and experience in electronics I have never met with any other meaning of that :).

Answer (score 0):

We can write:

\$ \frac{V_0}{V_g}=\frac{R_p||R_L}{R_p||R_L+R_s+R_g} \>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\>(1) \$

and

\$ R_g=R_{eq}=R_p||(R_s+R_g) \> \> \> \> \>\>(2)\$

Let
\$ \frac{V_0}{V_g}=0.125=k \$,

then, from the above equations, we can derive that

\$ R_p = (1+\frac {R_g}{R_s})R_g=(1+\frac {100}{R_s})100\$

and

\$ R_s = \frac{(1-k)R_L*R_p}{k(R_p+R_L)}-100=  \frac{(1-k)R_L*(1+\frac {100}{R_s})100}{k((1+\frac {100}{R_s})100+R_L)}-100 \$

Solve the last two equations for \$R_s\$ and \$R_p\$, substitute \$k\$, and...

that's it!

Note: Both \$ R_s\$ and \$R_p\$ are functions of the load resistance \$R_L\$, of course.

Well, later I solved it and the general solution (including an optional value of \$ R_g\$ and \$\frac{V_0}{V_g}\$) is as follows:

\$ R_s=\frac{R_L \cdot R_g}{k(R_L+R_g)}-R_g=\frac{R_L||R_g}{k}-R_g =\frac{V_g}{V_0} \cdot (R_L||R_g)-R_g\$

\$ R_p=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_g}-\frac{k}{\frac{1}{R_g}+\frac{1}{R_L}}}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_g}-\frac{k}{R_L||R_g}}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_g}-\frac{V_0}{V_s} \cdot \frac{1}{R_L||R_g}}\$

All this holds if both results \$R_p\$ and \$R_s\$ are greater than 0 and the denominator in the \$R_p\$ formula is different from 0, of course. The condition for it is obvious from the formulae.

Continued on Oct 19, 2017

The above-mentioned condition is \$R_L>\frac{k}{1-k} \cdot R_g\$ and the specific results for our case (\$k=0.125\$ and \$R_g=100\$):

\$ R_s = \frac{875R_L-12500}{1.25R_L+125}\$,

\$R_p = \frac{1000R_L}{8.75R_L-125}\$

under the following condition:

\$R_L>\frac{R_g}{7}\$